# Unable to replay jenkins pipeline, crumb error

Tags: jenkins, tomcat, http-status-code-403

I have a Jenkins pipeline which is fairly complicated with multiple shared libraries. I can run and rebuild the pipeline with no issues. However when it comes to replaying the pipeline I am hit with the following error.

[Jenkins 403 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2foRd.png)

Jenkins version: 2.401.3
Tomcat 9.0.78

The plugins are exactly the same on both jenkins instances
[List of Jenkins plugins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ez44l.png)

What other troubleshooting steps can I take?

- I have tried disabling CSRF but still encounter the error.
- On the replay I've removed all the code in the main script and replaced with a simple "hello world" script and still encounter the error.

The replay functionality works on another Jenkins instance with the same Jenkins\Tomcat version